# How safe are PostgreSQL CONCURRENTLY option

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.6

As I know `CONCURRENTLY` let DATABASE create an index without any lock though It could incur more CPU usage.

I am planning to create an index in production DATABASE with the option.

Before applying that I want to check for sure.

Is it safe enough to use in production DATABASE regardless of how many rows there and how many `INSERT`, `UPDATE` is executed while creating the index?

Comment: Yes, it's safe to be used in production. Otherwise the Postgres development team wouldn't have released it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is safe, meaning that it cannot damage your database and that the index will be correct once the statement succeeds.

Creating an index uses I/O and CPU resources, that is unavoidable.

If `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` fails, it will leave behind an invalid index that you should drop, since it uses space.

`CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` will require an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table, but differently from a normal `CREATE INDEX` which locks the table for the whole duration of the operation, it takes only a very short lock at the very end. This is normally not a problem, but it can be a problem if you have long running transactions that use the table: `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` will have to queue behind these transactions, and all later statements will have to queue behind it.

So make sure you have no long running transactions.